# Make Element Full Height of Page on Bubble.is

Tags: javascript, html

How can I make an element the full height of a page on the website editor of bubble.is. So, when opening the page on differently sized computer screens, my element would always cover the full height of the page. An example of this effect is https://kickpoint.ca/contact/

I’m thinking I may need to use html or JavaScript to do it, but I’m not sure how and if there’s a simpler solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What you actually want for this is css. I would read through a quick tutorial. I am not familar with Bubble.is, however css is for styling webpages. After a simple tutorial you will know exactly how to do what you are trying to do. It would be something like #element-id{ height: 100%}. or on the html element:

Comment: Thank you! The only problem is that I am not familiar with using CSS in Bubble.is

Comment: yeah, im sorry neither am i.